# Need assistance in moving code that is directly coded in a page to my site assets to allow parameters and reuse

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to move some code I have embedded on a page to my site assets to allow me to re-use this code by passing in parameters instead of duplicating this same code on multiple pages.

I have my script working when I place it directly into a script editor.  I am now trying to place it into my site assets and referencing it from a script editor.  I can not get it to work now.

The code below works perfectly when directly inserted into my page in a Script Editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //set section text and field name
    AddSectionBeforeField("Phase Section","Phase");

});
function AddSectionBeforeField(sectionText,fieldName){
    var $fieldTR=$(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+fieldName+"')").closest("tr");
    $fieldTR.before("<tr style='background-color:white'><td colspan='2' class='ms-formbody' style='padding:0; color: #96c03d;'><div style='font-size:22px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: Oswald';'>"+sectionText+"</div></td></tr>");
}

function changeButtonStyle()
{ 
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  

alert('aa');
    for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)  
    {   
       if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")
       {
          inputs[i].style.backgroundColor='#96C03D'; 
          inputs[i].style.color ='white';   
          inputs[i].style.width= "160px";
          inputs[i].style.height = "40px";
          inputs[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
       }
        if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Cancel")
       {
          inputs[i].style.backgroundColor='#96C03D'; 
          inputs[i].style.color ='white';   
          inputs[i].style.width= "160px";
          inputs[i].style.height = "40px";
          inputs[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
       }           
      }  
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeButtonStyle");
</script>
```

I then change my script editor to contain the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js-test/EditChanges.js"></script>
```

and in my asset library, my EditChanges.js contains the following code: (the same code with the exception of the  tags.

```
$(function () {
    //set section text and field name
    AddSectionBeforeField("Phase Section","Phase");

});
function AddSectionBeforeField(sectionText,fieldName){
    var $fieldTR=$(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+fieldName+"')").closest("tr");
    $fieldTR.before("<tr style='background-color:white'><td colspan='2' class='ms-formbody' style='padding:0; color: #96c03d;'><div style='font-size:22px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: Oswald';'>"+sectionText+"</div></td></tr>");
}

function changeButtonStyle()
{ 
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  

    for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)  
    {   
       if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")
       {
          inputs[i].style.backgroundColor='#96C03D'; 
          inputs[i].style.color ='white';   
          inputs[i].style.width= "160px";
          inputs[i].style.height = "40px";
          inputs[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
       }
        if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Cancel")
       {
          inputs[i].style.backgroundColor='#96C03D'; 
          inputs[i].style.color ='white';   
          inputs[i].style.width= "160px";
          inputs[i].style.height = "40px";
          inputs[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
       }           
      }  
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeButtonStyle");
```

I expect a header to be placed above the Phase field.

Comment: Seems weird it does not just have a class with CSS rules instead of all that JavaScript.

Comment: Well I'm not a proficient web developer and that might be why.  I did some testing with a very simple reference and it seems that a SharePoint wiki page might behave differently then the page that is "created" when editing a SharePoint list record.  A simple reference to this code in the site assets works on a SharePoint Page, but not the "page" when editing a list record. 
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    alert('Testing Referencing Javascript');
});

Comment: I have just figured out that the path for site assets is different if your on a wiki page versus being on a list "page".  I found some reference to reviewing javascript errors in the browser as step 1.  I'm working through these right now.

Comment: So when you look at the network panel is it a 404? Is there an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

***Not really an answer to your problem, but took much code for a comment.***

A simple CSS rule can allow you to avoid looping over to find the buttons to apply the styles.

```css
button[value="Cancel"],
button[value="Save"] {
  background-color: #96C03D;
  color: white;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
<button value="Save">Save</button>
<button value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I attempted to implement your css.  The only way that I know how is to add CEWP and have it point to a htm document and have that reference my css.  My htm document is:                                                                                              
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://share.health.wisconsin.gov/ltc/teams/ITRequeests/SiteAsets/css/ColorButtons.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Correction:I attempted to implement your css.  The only way that I know how is to add CEWP and have it point to a htm document and have that reference my css.  My htm document is:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://XXXXXXXXXXX/ltc/teams/ITRequests/SiteAssets/css/ColorButtons.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

And my CSS is exactly as you have coded it and placed in SiteAssets/css.  No effect.  No error messages as I look at the console using Chrome’s developer’s tools.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing and more observation.  The references for any scripts are relative to where the page is in the URL.  For a Site Page the reference for SiteAssets is ../SiteAssets.  For a List page the reference is ../../SiteAssets.  Pretty simple if you really think about it.  Sorry for wasting people's time, but this was something I didn't know.